# Unable to connect to Azure Redis Cache with SSL

Tags: azure, caching, ssl, redis, stackexchange.redis

Connecting to Azure Redis Cache like this, on Owin application startup...

```
var options = ConfigurationOptions.Parse(cacheConnectionString);
var kernel = new StandardKernel();
kernel.Bind<ConnectionMultiplexer>().ToMethod(context =>
{
    return ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(options);
}).InSingletonScope();
```

Which works absolutely fine for Redis running on my local machine, or for Azure Redis with SSL turned off. However, as soon as I change the connection string from:

`xyz.redis.cache.windows.net,ssl=false,password=abcdefghxyz=`

to

`xyz.redis.cache.windows.net,ssl=true,password=abcdefghxyz=`

It throws:

> It was not possible to connect to the redis server(s); to create a disconnected multiplexer, disable AbortOnConnectFail. UnableToResolvePhysicalConnection on PING

I'm using StackExchange.Redis version 1.0.316.0 from NuGet. I've tried...

- Creating different caches in Azure Portal. Hasn't worked over SSL with any of them :(
- Connecting without using Ninject
- Creating the ConfigurationOptions object manually rather than parsing a string

I'm all out of ideas for what could possibly be going wrong now though. Hopefully it's something trivial I've missed, but just can't see it!

**Edit**
I ran the `ConnectToAzure()` unit test, passing in my cache name and password and it passed. So I'm almost certainly doing something silly here.

**Edit 2**
It also works from a console application without any issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it, super-weird situation but I'll answer just in case someone else is ever sat equally as confused as I've been.

The project was previously a web role in an Azure Cloud Service, which had In-role caching enabled. We moved it to a standalone Azure Web App, but never got around to removing all the unnecessary references that were left over.

Removing `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime` and `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics` miraculously got it working.

Comment: I cannot find this reference Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime in my web code. My web app works well if ssl is selt to False. However fails when ssl= true, How can I resolve this